# Reconstruct regexp to get json

Tags: java, json

I would like to download webpage source code and get json.

[Here](http://satiksme.daugavpils.lv/tramvajs-nr-1-butlerova-iela-stacija) you can switch to source code, use `ctrl + F` and find `var data` this is what I need.
And there is my code for that:

```
public class Parser {

    static Pattern DATA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("var data = (.*)");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String webPage = new Parser().getUrlSource("http://satiksme.daugavpils.lv/tramvajs-nr-1-butlerova-iela-stacija");
        if(webPage != null){
            Matcher m = DATA_PATTERN.matcher(webPage);
            if(m.find()) {
                String extracted = m.group(1).trim();
                System.out.println(extracted);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
        URL yahoo = new URL(url);
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        return a.toString();
    }
}
```

The problem is that: `Pattern.compile("var data = (.*)")` is not working well. I would like to have only `json`, without additional html tags.

For now actual result is:

json +

```
$(document).ready(function () {        $(".sations ul").html("");        var selst = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");                $.each(data.stations, function (index, val) {            var cls = "even"; if (index % 2 == 0) cls = "odd";            $(".sations ul").append("<li class='" + cls + "' id='station-" + val.sid + "' onclick='return showStation(" + val.sid + ")'><span class='station-name'>" + val.name + "</span></li>");            if (index == 0) {                if (!selst)                    selst = val.sid;                                }        });        showStation(selst);        initmap(defaultLat, defaultLng, defaultZoom);    });</script></article></div>        </div>            </div></div></div><div id="layout-footer" class="group">    <footer id="footer">        <div id="footer-quad" class="group">                                            </div>        <div id="footer-sig" class="group">            <div class="zone zone-footer"><div class="credits"><span class="copyright">Copyright &#169; 2014 <b>SIA Daugavpils Satiksme</b>. All rightd reserved.</span><span class="poweredby">Izstrādāts <a href="http://www.latinsoft.lv" target="_blank">Latinsoft</a>. Izmantojot <a href="http://www.orchardproject.net" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Orchard</a>.</span></div><div class="user-display">        <span class="user-actions"><a href="/Users/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2Ftramvajs-nr-1-butlerova-iela-stacija" rel="nofollow">Sign In</a></span></div></div>        </div>    </footer></div></div><script src="/Modules/Traffic/scripts/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Modules/Traffic/scripts/dsapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Themes/TheThemeMachine/scripts/lispage.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/Themes/TheThemeMachine/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body></html>
```

Expected result: only json.

P.S. and this `Pattern` works perfect in Android. Maybe somebody can explain me why ?

Thank you!

Comment: Far from perfect or safe, but won't `"var data = (.*)[\\n;]"` do the trick?

Comment: @Siguza unfortunately no, I think I should to play with "$(document)"..

Comment: Oh, and just a heads up: That "JSON" isn't actually valid JSON, because it contains commas before array closing brackets (`,]`), which is valid in JavaScript but not JSON.

Comment: @Siguza thanks, I will think about it. My idea to find it and replace. But firstly, I should to fix my problem with excess html code.